# How can I locate a sheet by name from Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a Google Sheets spreadsheet with a large number of sheets. I want to find a particular sheet by sheet name from Google Sheets.

I know how to locate a sheet by name using a Google Application Script. However I can't figure out how to do it from Google Sheets itself.

Comment: Welcome. What do you mean by locate a sheet from the web application itself? Are you referring to Google Sheets or another web application?

Comment: Yes, from Google Sheets itself.

Comment: The [tag:google-apps-script] should not be removed because the accepted answer suggest the use of Google Apps Script. Tags could be included based on well received answers. By the way I didn't check if the three close-voter chosen the same closing reason. *I disagree with the closing reason shown*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Sheets user interface doesn't include a way to locate a sheet by name.

At the bottom there is a tab for each sheet, but they aren't sorted alphabetically and some sheets could be hidden; also there is a button that shows the list of sheets shown and hidden but this list isn't sorted either.

Google Apps Script could be used to find the sheet. I.E. the following script activates a sheet having the name `Sheet1`

```
function goToSheet(){
  var name = 'Sheet1'; // Change Sheet1 by the name of the sheet that you want to find
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadshet().getSheetByName(name);
  sheet.activate();
}
```

Google Apps Script is very powerful, it includes prompts to ask the user to write the name of the sheet to look for, also includes the HTML Service that could be used to create custom dialogs and sidebars.

References

- [Extending Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets)
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#activate

Answer (score -2):

If using QUERY is applicable you can do it.

Example:

`QUERY({'your sheet name'!A1:W293},"select Col3,SUM(Col5) where Col1>=datetime '2019-08-01 00:00:00' and Col1<=datetime '2019-08-31 23:59:59' group by Col3 order by SUM(Col5) desc limit 10 label Col3 'Track', SUM(Col5) 'Sum'")`

or

`QUERY('your sheet name'!B:E, "select E where (D='" & $B9 & "' and B='" & $A9 & "')label E ''")`

Comment: Actually, this should work: ='your sheet name'!B23